# Duplicate elements in array using Hash Table in C++

Tags: c++, hash

Can someone give an example of finding array duplicates using a Hash table and a function.

I am looking for some examples in C++.
The codes I am getting are all in Java.

Comment: finding array duplicate as in getting the position of the duplicates in the array ?

Comment: I want to get the array duplicate elements

Comment: Please show your own efforts. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please see the specifications of the library you're using for implementation of `HashTable` and how it handles the `HashCollision` , then and only then you can get an efficient way to handle the duplicate value if you're using the default `HashFunction` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to put in a hash table the element of the array (as key) and their number of occurrence (as value).
Then you copy the key of the hash table where the associated value is more than 1.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<int> vec{1,1,2,3,1,4,5};
    std::map<int, int> m;
    // We copy the element of the vector into the hash table
    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&m](auto & elt){ m[elt] += 1; });
    std::vector<int> res;
    // We select the key where the value is > 1
    std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [&res](auto & elt) { if(elt.second > 1) res.push_back(elt.first); });
}
```